# gdb 'Reading symbols ... done' but still no symbols

Tags: linux, gdb, debug-symbols

My project compile with Address Sanitizer using gcc/g++ 4.8,

when debugging with gdb, it shows "Reading symbols from xxxx done"

but when break on setting breakpoint, I can't find any symbols,

type "info args" just returned "No symbol table info available."

can't use print var, it just tell me 'No symbol "var" in current context.'

I can confirm those *.so files have symbols with using nm command,

and "Show Symbols in File xxx" from qtcreator it shows those symbols.

But if compile without Address Sanitizer, gdb works just fine.

I remember several months ago it works fine on Arch Linux, but now don't on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your codes?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. The project is too big, about 7G...

Comment: Have you compiled your sources using "-g" option. If compiled with "-g" option, then only you will have debug symbols embedded in your object or shared library or exe files.

Comment: Sorry I found this is the gdb problem,
version higher than 7.4 works just fine.

Using 7.4 just because QtCreator don't work with 7.6 or higher version of gdb.
Now I'm upgrage gdb to 7.5, it solved those problems.

And sorry again for my fault...